# Incorrect return type from an ArrayList of an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an array list of an array list that should be full of Integers, but when I try to compile the program, I get an error stating that it cannot add numbers to it because of incompatible operand types Object and Int. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int ntt = 20;
        ArrayList<Integer> Factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<List> FactorsList = new ArrayList<List>();
        ArrayList<Integer> Occurences = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Smallest Multiple of Numbers 1-20\n---------------------------------\n\nSearching...");


        for(int i = 2; i <= ntt; i++){

            FactorsList.add(isPrime(i));

        }

        for(int i = 2; i <= ntt; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < FactorsList.size(); j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < FactorsList.get(j).size();k++){

            if(FactorsList.get(j).get(k)==i){
                Occurences.set(i, i+1);
            }

        }

    }

    static List<Long> isPrime(long num){
        List<Long> ar = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for(long count=2;count<=num;count++){
                while(num%count == 0){
                ar.add(count);
                num /= count;
            }
        }
        return ar;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, you can declare `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: You've got a mixture of `Long` and `Integer` storing your numbers.  You should probably choose one or the other and stick to it.  Also, have you tried changing `factorList` to being a `List<? extends List<Integer>>` or something similar?

Comment: @DavidWallace if you do that, you won't be able to add anything into that `List`.

Comment: Ooh, yeah, right.  Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in java class names start with uppercase letters, field names start with lowercase letters. I suggest you use some kine of IDE for developing, you will get all kind of hints/warnings/errors what you are doing wrong.

Use a `List<Long>` since you are working with `long` values. You are using generics, use them correctly: `ArrayList<List<Long>> factorsList = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();`

In `occurences.set(i, i + 1);` you assign something at a index that does not exist, since the list is empty!

That being said, my guess is that a `Map` would be the better data structure for you. Take a peek at the [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html) that ship with java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the Eclipse IDE, but did not get that warning. I only got the warning that use of the default package is discouraged and that the main method has a constructor name. However thanks for the info and i will remember that in the future. Also after I got past the error message using Luiggi's solution I found the other error :P. And from what i've read about a Map it does look like it would be better here. Thanks again for the help :D